# Full-length menu on left, two content panes on right: DIV-and-CSS-only approach?

Tags: css, layout, html

I'm trying to create a simple web page that resembles the following:

[image]

I've got three DIVs, as follows:

```
<div class="leftNav">       
</div>
<div class="topPanel">          
</div>
<div class="bottomPanel">           
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
.leftNav
{
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;    
}

.topPanel
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    float: right;
}
.bottomPanel
{
    width: 80%;
    height: 50%;
    float: right;
}
```

The end result, however, looks completely out-of-whack.  Is it possible to create such a thing with DIVs and CSS?

Comment: Do you want the three `div`s together to fill the viewport? Where should scrollbars appear, if anywhere?

Comment: No scrolling.  The "leftNav" should fill the viewport from top to bottom, on the left; and the top and bottom panels should fill half the screen from top to bottom, respectively, on the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this.

You can fix your original approach simply by adding this:

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden; /* to hide any scrollbars that might appear */
}
```

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/n4wr4/

Comment: Setting height:100% on html, body, catches people every time.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to get those three divs inside a container div and set the size for that container. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/Rorok_89/A6Uf7/

Comment: You do actually have the right sort of idea. Except that the "containers" are already there - `html` and `body`. http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/A6Uf7/1/

Comment: You're right, just specifying the height for html or body was enough. Better your way, saves needless divs. Cheers!